# MATLAB plot x,y from Loop

Tags: matlab, plot

I wonder why these two code doesn't produce the same plot?

code 1:

```
x=[2,5,7];
y=[10,4,3];
plot(x,y);
```

code 2:

```
x=[2,5,7];
y=[10,4,3];

for i=1:length(x)
    xx=x(i);
    yy=y(i);
    plot(xx,yy);

end
```

EDITED:
How I can make the output of `Code 2` similar to output in `Code 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Code 1

You're drawing a **line** with the `x` and `y` coordinates defined in the vectors with the `plot(x,y)` command. By default, it means `plot(x,y,'-');` which means you draw a line (`-`).

#### Code 2

You're drawing individual points (no line) stored in the vectors since you're calling `plot` for each point (`xx`,`yy`)

You can duplicate the effect in Code 2 in Code 1, with the following change:

```
plot(x,y,'.');
```

This forces MATLAB to only plot the **points** and not the connecting line

If you want the points **and** the line,

```
plot(x,y,'-.');
```

For more details, check out the documentation of the [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) command.

#### Sample Code:

```
%# If you know the number of elements, preallocate
%# else just initialize xx = []; and yy =[];
xx = zeros(100,1);
yy = zeros(100,1);

%# Get the data
for i = 1:length(xx)
    xx(i) = getXSomehow();
    yy(i) = getYSomehow();
end

%# Plot the data
plot(xx,yy);
```

Comment: Jacob@ Thanks, but actually for some reasons I have need to read the x and y through loop and I want to produce the output as in Code 1. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: No, you'll have to store it in a vector and then plot it.

Answer (score 3):

[Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219739/matlab-plot-x-y-from-loop/3219760#3219760) addresses why the two pieces of code give different results. In response to your comment about needing to read `x` and `y` in a loop while plotting, here's one solution that will allow you to update the plot line with each value read using the [GET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/get.html) and [SET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/set.html) commands:

```
hLine = plot(nan,nan,'-.');  %# Initialize a plot line (points aren't displayed
                             %#   initially because they are NaN)
for i = 1:10                       %# Loop 10 times
  x = ...;                         %# Get your new x value somehow
  y = ...;                         %# Get your new y value somehow
  x = [get(hLine,'XData') x];      %# Append new x to existing x data of plot
  y = [get(hLine,'YData') y];      %# Append new y to existing y data of plot
  set(hLine,'XData',x,'YData',y);  %# Update the plot line
  drawnow;                         %# Force the plot to refresh
end
```

If you aren't going to loop a specific number of times, but simply want to loop while some condition is true, you can use a [WHILE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/while.html) loop instead of a [FOR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/for.html) loop.

Comment: Thank you. How I can add some text on the plot showing the sequence of the coordinate? e.g. 1,2,3...n?

Comment: @Jessy: You can use the [TEXT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/text.html) function to place text at a given set of coordinates. For example, you could put this in your loop after you read `x` and `y`: `text(x,y,int2str(i));`